# How to create nodes in c++?

Tags: c++

Write a function to insert a node to the head of the linked list. The function takes two arguments: a pointer to the first node in the double linked list and a string value. It should create a new node with the given value to the head of the double linked list.

This is the question I need to answer. I'm not looking for the answer I'm just unsure how to create a node in C++.

Comment: What are you unsure about?  What data members should a node have a for a doubly linked list?

Comment: should it be like     Node* insertNode()

Comment: You can create a new node with `new node`

Comment: @Sammy2000 The task is `The function takes two arguments: a pointer to the first node in the double linked list and a string value`.  Does `Node* insertNode()` do that?

Comment: no, i need to include (Node* head, string value) right?

Comment: @Sammy2000 Correct.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, we have learned about classes. But, I'm still very shaky on nodes and linked lists so I'm having trouble really with understanding the question.

Comment: if I type class node, does that create a class named node?

Comment: Always search the internet first.  There already are a plethora of linked list examples.  Try these terms: C++ node linked list.

Comment: @Sammy2000 Note that "node" in the context of linked lists has a specific meaning that is not general to C++. Specifically it is a `struct` or a `class` with specific members. I suggest that you read your textbook and other class materials over and over to help learn the concept. You should also make use of your instructor's office hours, TAs, and online resources.

Comment: As for understanding the question, I suggest taking it a few words at a time. NathanOliver has been pointing you in that direction and you have figured out how to translate "The function takes two arguments: a pointer to the first node in the double linked list and a string value" to code. Then the next step is to figure out how to write "It should create a new node" in C++. This is where classes come in. First you have to define the `node` class. Then you have to learn about creating instances of that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be what you wanted.

```cpp
struct node{
    node * next;
    std::string value;
};

node * addToTheFront(node * front, std::string value){
    node * temp = new node;
    temp->next = front;
    temp->value = value;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::move()` the passed value into the `node`? Or if not doing that, at least don't pass by value, just `const&`.

Comment: "The function takes two arguments: (...) and a string value." - Isn't he being asked to pass that "by value"? Of course it's much better using const&, but that wasn't what he asked for.

Comment: Yes. And if you receive the string by value, you can and probably should move that local string into the node, otherwise you copy it for no reason.